# issue in python beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am running this python script using beautiful soup.The url which i have mentioned has 53 products.When i extract it using beautiful soup i only get first 16 items.The code look perfect.Please find below the code.

Can someone please help me..!!

```
Import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as url_req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search- 
alias%3Daps&field-keywords=tommy+hilfiger+shirt"
uclient= url_req(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()

#html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
titles = page_soup.findAll("a",{"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page 
s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal"})
for title in titles:
print(title.text)
```

**Output:**

Tommy Hilfiger Men's Plain Slim Fit Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Polo
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Checkered Cotton Casual Shirt (A7BMW112_Cabernet-Pt_L)
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Solid Slim Fit Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Plain Regular Fit Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Solid Regular Fit T-Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Printed Slim Fit Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Polo
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirt
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Casual Shirts
Tommy Hilfiger Men's Plain Cotton Casual Shirt (A7BMW105_Cabernet-Pt_L)

Comment: there are some li tags where the data is generated dynamically that is why you are able to get only 16 text..i suggest switching to selenium

Comment: Thanks for the update.Can you please update the above code and help me get the correct output.

Comment: i would suggest to see for yourself..read the selenium doc and try.. if you get stuck then ping me i'll help